referenceerror: sessionstorage is not defined angular
My project is running but i am getting error in terminal.
 let obj = {
      doc_id: sessionStorage.getItem('doc_id'),
      batch_no: sessionStorage.getItem('batch_no')
    }

I tried to add as below but still that error present in terminal.
But my project works in angular 17
let obj = {
      doc_id: sessionStorage?.getItem('doc_id'),
      batch_no: sessionStorage?.getItem('batch_no')
    }


Can you share us some context of your app, are you using SSR ?

Maybe you're using session storage in Server Side Component

Try checking if the code is running on the browser and then try accessing sessionStorage!
If you are using SSR, then there is do window, document, localStorage and sessionStorage existing to check!
private readonly platformId = inject(PLATFORM_ID);
...

...
if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)){ 
    console.log('browser'); 
    let obj = {
        doc_id: sessionStorage?.getItem('doc_id'),
        batch_no: sessionStorage?.getItem('batch_no')
    }
}

